# Performing image classification from Nearmap WMS in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, wms, classification, image

I have a subscription to Nearmap that provides me with WMS Server link to their images. I would like to perform image classification using this imagery however I can't work out how to use the WMS feed for classification in ArcGiS (v10.3.1) short of exporting a series of maps as a raster.

I've tried Arc's "make image server layer" tool however I can't seem to select an image service layer. I get to the point in the attached image and can't select anything.

Does anyone know how I do this?

[image: can't select image service layer]

Comment: Can you use the WMS to download a layer image then work on that image as a standalone data source?

Answer (score 1):

The [Make Image Server Layer](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/make-image-server-layer.htm) tool:

> Creates a temporary raster layer from an image service. The layer that
>   is created will not persist after the session ends unless the document
>   is saved.

but it sounds like you have a WMS and not an image service so I think you should try the help for [Adding WMS services](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/web-maps-and-services/adding-wms-services.htm) instead because it describes how:

> WMS server content can be used in ArcMap (as well as ArcGlobe) as map layers.